# calculate the score with respect to the group it was assigned or other

Tags: python, pandas, cluster-analysis

I'm beginner in python, I have two dataframes as below. The first dataframe represents the user with their vectors and group number.

```
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['user 1', 'user 2', 'user 3', 'user 4', 'user 5'], 'x1': [[0.2, 0.3, 0.5],[0.3, 0.3, 0.4],[0.4, 0.4, 0.2],[0.2, 0.1, 0.7],[0.5,0.3,0.2]],'group': [1, 0, 0, 2, 1]})

df1
```

output:

```
 user   x1  group
    0   user 1  [0.2, 0.3, 0.5] 1
    1   user 2  [0.3, 0.3, 0.4] 0
    2   user 3  [0.4, 0.4, 0.2] 0
    3   user 4  [0.2, 0.1, 0.7] 2
    4   user 5  [0.5, 0.3, 0.2] 1
```

the second dataframe represents the group number with its vector and variable (p2) and its threshold

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'group': [0, 1, 2],
                   'x2': [[0.4, 0.2, 0.4],[0.5, 0.1, 0.4], [0.5, 0.1, 0.4]],
                   'p2': [0.231, 0.342, 0.411],
                   'threshold': [0.9, 0.6, 0.8]})
df2
```

output:

```
group   x2  p2  threshold
0   0   [0.4, 0.2, 0.4] 0.231   0.9
1   1   [0.5, 0.1, 0.4] 0.342   0.6
2   2   [0.5, 0.1, 0.4] 0.411   0.8
```

I am trying to calculate for each user, the score (S) with respect to the group it was assigned by using:

[image]

where k= group size and T is the transport matrix of (x2 -x1).

How could I do that for all users?

Comment: start with `df1.join(df2[['x2', 'p2', 'threshold']], on='group')`, then you have one DataFrame with all the data you need to calculate S for each row.

Comment: @ The Photon, thank you, could you extend your example with a code that assigns the user to the group for each score higher or lower the threshold? like in the example of user 1 when S higher that threshold?

Comment: What does "assign the user to the group for each the score is below the threshold" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar answer to @The Photon, where we (1) merge df1 and df2, (2) calculate `k` with groupby (3) calculate (x2-x1) inner product with itself

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['user 1', 'user 2', 'user 3', 'user 4', 'user 5'],
                    'x1': [[0.2, 0.3, 0.5],[0.3, 0.3, 0.4],[0.4, 0.4, 0.2],[0.2, 0.1, 0.7],[0.5,0.3,0.2]],
                    'group': [1, 0, 0, 2, 1]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'group': [0, 1, 2],
                    'x2': [[0.4, 0.2, 0.4],[0.5, 0.1, 0.4], [0.5, 0.1, 0.4]],
                    'p2': [0.231, 0.342, 0.411],
                    'threshold': [0.9, 0.6, 0.8]})

#merge df1 and df2 into a single table
merged_df = df1.merge(df2)

#calculate the number of unique users per group (k)
merged_df['k'] = merged_df.groupby('group')['user'].transform('nunique')

#calculate x2-x1 for each user (convert to numpy array for vectorized subtraction)
x2_sub_x1 = merged_df['x2'].apply(np.array)-merged_df['x1'].apply(np.array)

#calculate (x2-x1)T(x2-x1) for each user (same as squaring each term and summing)
numerator = x2_sub_x1.pow(2).apply(sum)

#calculate S from your formula and add it as a column to the merged table
merged_df['S'] = (1/merged_df['k'])+(numerator/merged_df['p2'])
```

Final merged table

```
    user    x1  group   x2  p2  threshold   k   S
0   user 1  [0.2, 0.3, 0.5] 1   [0.5, 0.1, 0.4] 0.342   0.6 2   0.909357
1   user 5  [0.5, 0.3, 0.2] 1   [0.5, 0.1, 0.4] 0.342   0.6 2   0.733918
2   user 2  [0.3, 0.3, 0.4] 0   [0.4, 0.2, 0.4] 0.231   0.9 2   0.586580
3   user 3  [0.4, 0.4, 0.2] 0   [0.4, 0.2, 0.4] 0.231   0.9 2   0.846320
4   user 4  [0.2, 0.1, 0.7] 2   [0.5, 0.1, 0.4] 0.411   0.8 1   1.437956
```

Comment: I'm unclear on what needs to happen. Can a single user be assigned to multiple groups? Does the value of `k` change as you move users from one group to the other? If so, then moving a single user from group1 to group2 would change the scores of all group1 and group2 users? Maybe ask a new stackoverflow question for this part?

Answer (score 2):

First, count up the members of each group to get the *k* term:

```
df2['count'] = df1.groupby('group')['user'].count()
```

Then merge `df1` and `df2` so that we have a frame with all necessary parameters for each user in a single row:

```
joined = df1.join(df2[['x2', 'p2', 'threshold', 'count']], on='group')
print(joined)

>>>      user               x1  group               x2     p2  threshold  count
0  user 1  [0.2, 0.3, 0.5]      1  [0.5, 0.1, 0.4]  0.342        0.6      2
1  user 2  [0.3, 0.3, 0.4]      0  [0.4, 0.2, 0.4]  0.231        0.9      2
2  user 3  [0.4, 0.4, 0.2]      0  [0.4, 0.2, 0.4]  0.231        0.9      2
3  user 4  [0.2, 0.1, 0.7]      2  [0.5, 0.1, 0.4]  0.411        0.8      1
4  user 5  [0.5, 0.3, 0.2]      1  [0.5, 0.1, 0.4]  0.342        0.6      2
```

Now define functions to calculate the S score:

```
def l_delta(z1, z2):
    return [a1 - a2 for (a1, a2) in zip(z1, z2)]

def inner(z1, z2):
    return sum([a1 * a2 for (a1, a2) in zip(z1, z2)])

def s_score(row):
    delta = l_delta(row['x2'], row['x1'])
    num = inner(delta, delta)
    return 1/row['count'] + num / row['p2']
```

Finally, apply these functions to each row in the joined matrix:

```
joined['s_score'] = joined.apply(s_score, axis=1)
print(joined[['user', 's_score']])
```

Result:

```
     user   s_score
0  user 1  0.909357
1  user 2  0.586580
2  user 3  0.846320
3  user 4  1.437956
4  user 5  0.733918
```

Comment: thank you, what about users 1, 4, and 5 whose scores are higher than the threshold? we should calculate the score for the other groups and assign the user to the group for each score below the threshold.

Comment: @alxander21, sorry I didn't understand those requirements. Since the count of group members affects the score, I think you'd have to re-calculate everything after you re-assign users to different groups. Then you might have to iterate until the group assignments become stable (or maybe they wouldn't and you'd never find a consistent solution)